# Retyping int to double to state height from centimeters to meters c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> // try to convert height in centimeters to meters

using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        int height_cm ; // declaring first int in centimeters
        cout << " State your height in centimeters: " << endl ; // stating
        cin >> height_cm ; /* I was thinking also of storing this value for later reusage in retyping but I don´t know how to do it */
        double (height_cm) ; /* here is the problem,debugger says that I can not declare height_cm again because I had declared it as int before , but I´m actually trying to retype it */
        height_cm /= 100 ; /* I´m also not sure about this , I think this assignment should be possible to get number in meters */
        cout << " Your height in meters is: " << height_cm << endl ; /* this should give me height in meters */
        return 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: Please [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48972815/edit) the the text of your question as text, not as code comments, take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: You can't "retype" variables.

Comment: Thank you! I´ll definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, as your compiler is saying, you are trying to use the same name (height_cm) for another variable. Try doing:

```
...
double height_m = height_cm/100.0;
cout << " Your height in meters is: " << height_m<< endl ;
...
```

This way the meter variable will have a new name and the compiler will compile. Moreover, note that I divided `height_cm` by `100.0` instead of `100`. This is because `100` is an `int` and `100.0` is a `float` or `double`. If you use `int` then you would have an [`int` division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division) meaning that you would lose the decimal part.

A part from that:

- *I was thinking also of storing this value for later usage in retyping but I don´t know how to do it*: The `cin>>height_cm;` code takes whatever the user has typed, converts it to `int` and stores it in a variable called `height_cm` that you can use anytime you want in the current function (in this case `main()`).
- *I´m also not sure about this, I think this assignment should be possible to get number in meters*: That code would compile with no problem. However, this would end up with an [`int` divison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division). If you want you can do:

Code:

```
...
double height_m(height_cm);// this converts the int to double and stores it in the new variable height_m
height_m /= 100;// Divide the double variable height_m by 100 and store it again in height_m
...
```

Note that in this case although you are using `100` instead of `100.0` that would not be an `int` division because `height_m` is a `double`.